# Why does adding "and" disrupt how the line of code works?

Tags: python, django

So right now I have

```
if request.POST['superPoints'].count('.') == False:
```

then it goes on to other code. But if I add in

```
if request.POST['cashTexts'].count('.') and request.POST['superPoints']('.') == False:
```

it always goes to the else: statement regardless what is entered in the two forms. So when you try to count two things does something else that isn't False show up and disrupt the flow? Why won't conjoining these statements work?

EDIT:
It works if I do this:

```
if request.POST['cashTexts'].count('.') == False:
```

So I don't think it's a problem with one of the fields.

EDIT:: It work if i set them to !=True. not sure why exactly but I must have been getting something besides false.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if not request.POST['cashTexts'].count('.') and not request.POST['superPoints']:
```

I believe your problem has to do with operator precedence.

You were doing:

```
test1 and test2 == False
```

This translates to:

```
test1 and (test2 == False)
```

Which is the same as:

```
test1 == True and test2 == False
```

Comment: that makes it so that the cashtexts has to be true and superpoints has to be false right? I need them both to be False but for whatever reason setting them == to False doesn't work

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't understand that from your question! So if you want both false... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sooo I tried doing `if request.POST['cashTexts'].count('.')== False and request.POST['superPoints'] == False:`but it still wouldn't go to anything but the else statement

Comment: Please do not compare with `False` use negation instead. E.g.: `test1 and not test2` It is a smarter way to do the same! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to test for truthness in Python is:

```
if obj:
    pass
```

instead of:

```
if obj == True:
    pass
```

Similarily for falseness:

```
if not obj:
    pass
```

instead of:

```
if obj == False:
    pass
```

Also, `.count()` method of string returns the number of occurance of a substring. If you just want to test if a character is at least once in the string, use this:

```
if '.' in mystr:
    pass
```

If you want to test if a character is not in the string, use this:

```
if '.' not in mystr:
    pass
```

So if you want to test if there are no dots in either of the fields, do this:

```
if '.' not in request.POST['cashTexts'] and '.' not in request.POST['superPoints']:
    pass
```

Comment: Or use De Morgan's law to pull the 'not' to the outside:  if not ('.' in request.POST['cashTexts'] or '.' in request.POST['superPoints'])

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to keep it simple and get him going. He obviously has hard time understanding the logic.